# How to sum excel rows until an occurence of next item appears

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a table that looks like this:

| X | Y |
| --- | --- |
| Name01 | 0 |
| SomethingA | value |
| SomethingB | value |
| Name02 | 0 |
| SomethingA | value |
| Name03 | 0 |
| SomethingA | value |
| SomethingB | value |
| SomethingC | value |

I want to Sum Y values in groups, by NameX:

| X | Y |
| --- | --- |
| Name01 | values01 |
| Name02 | values02 |
| Name03 | values03 |

How to do that?
Problem is that the amount of rows for each of "Names" varies

Comment: Welcome! Are you promising that no **value** will be **0** unless it's another **NameXX**? Because I don't see any other way to split the data into groups in your sample table.

Comment: It could be, all the names have underscore "_" in their name so I just made a column that is 0 when there is an underscore, or 1 when there is no underscore:

Comment: This should be doable with pivot tables.

Answer (score 0):

**The Reverse Accumulator:**

There are plenty of ways to do this with complicated sumifs and array formulas but I prefer going old school for problems like this.

Start at the very last row (say row 99), in a new column (say col C). So C99 is

```
=IF(B100=0,B99,C100+B99)
```

Now copy and paste this formula upwards to the top. If you want, run a filter for all B=0 rows.

Edit:

You may change the IF condition to directly detect the name category based on the qualifying criteria (e.g. the underscore) and leave the corresponding Y column as an empty string "" instead of a zero.

Then go a step further and sum the inbetween numbers as negatives and use conditional formatting to white-out negative numbers, giving you a nice accounting style of subtotaling.

Comment: Another way to do this, that provides a nice summary in a duplicate table, is to use a pivot table. First add a "category" column and in a similar way to the above formula but top down, generate '=IF(B2=0, A2, C1)'. Now do the pivot with categories in "Rows". You can even add "X" column as "Rows" too which will make for a collapsible breakdown per category.

Comment: I first looked at your “reverse accumulator” and thought “that doesn’t sound right to me.”  Took another look and it’s genius.  The one change I might suggest, is that if one of the “something’s” values is zero, it breaks your accumulator.  Instead of B100=0, the better way is to search A100 for an underscore, which is authoritative that it’s “Name” row and not an inadvertent zero value.

Comment: I like your term "reverse accumulator"! Will be using it from now on! If the solution worked for you, kindly checkmark the solution as solved!

Answer (score 0):

Of course, this task is easily solved with the help of additional (auxiliary) columns and several not very complex formulas or with the help of PowerQuery (on the Data tab in modern versions of Excel). However, the old (very old) school suggests that if you know how to solve a problem by hand, you can teach VBA to do it for you.

The [**user-defined function (UDF)**](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-custom-functions-in-excel-2f06c10b-3622-40d6-a1b2-b6748ae8231f) is not very complex, it takes not much more button clicks to write it than to construct formulas, and the result is the same:

```
Option Explicit

Function sumByGroup(aSource As Range, Optional markAsName As String = "_") As Variant
Dim aData As Variant
Dim aResult As Variant
Dim i As Long, k As Long
Rem Get data from source range:
    aData = aSource.Value2
Rem Prepare and clear result array:
    ReDim aResult(1 To UBound(aData, 1), 1 To 2)
    For i = 1 To UBound(aData, 1)
        aResult(i, 1) = "": aResult(i, 2) = ""
    Next i
Rem Fill result array:
    k = 1
    aResult(k, 1) = aData(1, 1): aResult(k, 2) = aData(1, 2)
    For i = 2 To UBound(aData, 1)
        If InStr(aData(i, 1), markAsName) Then
            k = k + 1
            aResult(k, 1) = aData(i, 1): aResult(k, 2) = 0
        Else
            aResult(k, 2) = aResult(k, 2) + aData(i, 2)
        End If
    Next i
    sumByGroup = aResult
End Function
```

[image: Demo Result]